# installations errors vue js cli on windows

Tags: node.js, vue.js, nodes

going to install vue cli on windows but when check vue cli version using `vue -v` it is encounting following error messages. I have installed `npm 9.2.0` and `node`v16.16.0

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7601]
Copyright (c) 2009 Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

C:\Users\Mara>vue v
node:os:68
      throw new ERR_SYSTEM_ERROR(ctx);
      ^

SystemError [ERR_SYSTEM_ERROR]: A system error occurred: uv_os_gethostname retur
ned ENOSYS (function not implemented)
    at new Defaults (C:\node32\node_modules\@vue\cli\node_modules\@achrinza\node
-ipc\entities\Defaults.js:26:20)
    at new Parser (C:\node32\node_modules\@vue\cli\node_modules\@achrinza\node-i
pc\entities\EventParser.js:8:14)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\node32\node_modules\@vue\cli\node_modules\@achrinz
a\node-ipc\dao\client.js:11:19)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1105:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1159:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\node32\node_modules\@vue\cli\node_modules\@achrinz
a\node-ipc\services\IPC.js:4:14) {
  code: 'ERR_SYSTEM_ERROR',
  info: {
    errno: -4054,
    code: 'ENOSYS',
    message: 'function not implemented',
    syscall: 'uv_os_gethostname'
  },
  errno: [Getter/Setter],
  syscall: [Getter/Setter]
}

C:\Users\Mara>
```

how could I fix this problem here?

Comment: Please indicate the Windows version as well

Comment: it is windows 7

Comment: Look at the similar issue here https://github.com/nodemailer/nodemailer/issues/1410#issuecomment-1124005921